# How change , on new line in string MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, string

I have string variable like this

```
declare @string nvarchar(200) 
set @string = N'table1,table2,table3'
```

and I want to change comma on new line to have every table in new line.

I'm trying something like this but it doesn't work

```
 select replace(@string,',',char(13))
```

Comment: What doesn't work? What you posted does what you wrote - put each string in a separate line in the text. It won't split the string or convert the single string to multiple rows. Tables aren't files and table rows aren't text lines

Comment: If you want to split the string, `STRING_SPLIT` was introduced in SQL Server 2016

Answer (score 0):

it should work. Depending on your system you should consider using char(13) + char(10)
Line feed: char(10)
Carriage return: char(13)

```
declare @string nvarchar(200) 
set @string = N'table1,table2,table3' 
print replace(@string,',',char(13) + char(10))
```

if you copy it from your SSMS Result table it may remove the lines

Comment: It works, thanks :)